# Updating Sharepoint List items

Tags: powershell

I got a custom Sharepoint list which has the following list items

```
Hostname  -   IP   -     OS     -    CPUs - RAM -    Disk

Server      1.1.1.1   Server 2003     3      8    Disk C: 20gb
```

If i then change, lets say, the RAM so there is now 12gb (or CPU or any of the other values) i would like it to update it)

I got scripts that pull all the information from the servers via WMI and exporting it to a .csv

The csv layout looks like the following

```
IP,Hostname,OS,CPU,Ram,Disk
1.1.1.1,Server,Server 2003,3,12,Disk C: 20gb
```

Now here's the real question, i got a script that add's the items to the list, but if i run it again it adds the item to the list so its now there twice, (one with the old value and one with the new) but i need a script that can update the diffrent column values if they should change, without having to remove the item and add it again with the new values.

Comment: How about share your script or at least give us the absolute basic info needed to help you out - how are you updating SharePoint? SharePoint OM, Client OM, Web Services, Power shell or something else?

Comment: I tagged it as Powershell so thats what im using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the item ID you are updating, supposing you are using powershell (the tag you have put), it is like that:
Let's assume your list name is Servers

```
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite(spserver)
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$spList = $web.Lists["Servers"]
$serverItem = $spList.GetItemByID(1)
$serverItem["RAM"] = 12
$serverItem.Update()
```

In the GetItemByID methof you must put the correct ID of an item that you wish to update.

If you have your own identifier - let say you know that IPs are unique, you'll need to select item by that field, using CAML query.